# run pytest with seleniumbase failed: "argparse.ArgumentError: argument --variables: conflicting option string: --variables"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, seleniumbase

when running a test case, it gives this error whereas if I only use Selenium it works properly and test case gets executed

```
from selenium import webdriver
from seleniumbase import BaseCase


class OpenWebPageTest(BaseCase):
    def test_open_webpage(self):
        # Using Selenium WebDriver to open the webpage
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get('https://test01.rubiscape.io/#/auth/login-user')
        self.assert_true("Example Domain" in driver.title)

        # Using SeleniumBase to capture a screenshot
        self.check_window(name="Initial_Window")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    OpenWebPageTest().test_open_webpage()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please *read* tag descriptions before using them. From [tag:selenium-webdriver]: "When using this tag, also add a tag for the programming language you are using." I presume Python in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The conflicting option string, `--variables`, means that you have at least two different `pytest` plugins installed that are initializing the `--variables` option. `pytest` options can only be initialized once. This means you have to uninstall one of plugins.

By calling `pytest -h`, you can see which plugins the `--variables` option is being initialized from.

You also avoid this issue by installing dependencies into separate Python virtual environments. In your case, the `pytest` plugins that initialize `--variables` (one is SeleniumBase) should be separated.

Virtual Environment tutorial:
https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment

Comment: thank you for the response. Turns out I had pytest-selenium installed which adds pytest-variables as well. That is why I was getting the error. Uninstalled and it works perfectly now